# invokeinterface - count value

Tags: java, jvm, bytecode

I am trying to understand JVM bytecode, but I came across the following code:

```
58: invokeinterface #5,  1            // InterfaceMethod java/util/List.stream:()Ljava/util/stream/Stream;
63: invokedynamic #6,  0              // InvokeDynamic #0:test:()Ljava/util/function/Predicate;
68: invokeinterface #7,  2            // InterfaceMethod java/util/stream/Stream.filter:(Ljava/util/function/Predicate;)Ljava/util/stream/Stream;
```

It seems like *count* value is always *nargs* + 1 (in 58: should be 0 but is 1, in 68: should be 1 but is 2).

According to [JVM doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.invokeinterface):

> The count operand is an unsigned byte that must not be zero

Is that the reason why a number of arguments seem to be *nargs* + 1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`this` object (called `objectref` in JVMS) is always the first implicit argument of `invokeinterface`. It is passed on the operand stack along with other `nargs` arguments.

In fact, `count` is not the number of arguments, but rather a number of stack slots required to pass arguments. Actually, this byte is not typically used by the modern JVMs, see [notes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se11/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.invokeinterface):

> The count operand of the invokeinterface instruction records a measure
>   of the number of argument values, where an argument value of type long
>   or type double contributes two units to the count value and an
>   argument of any other type contributes one unit. This information can
>   also be derived from the descriptor of the selected method. The
>   redundancy is historical.

Comment: I saw that info about redundancy, but still was curious why value is different. Now it makes sense, thank you ;)

Comment: Do we know *why* the count was used at some point?